Do I need my own RPC node to use getProgramAccounts or getTokenLargestAccounts?
I need to use both of those methods locally. They seem to require account indexing. Is there any free RPC provider that has it or do I need to run my own node?

Both of these methods are quite compute heavy, so yes, you should get your own RPC. There are alternatives to getProgramAccount which are faster (indexers and such). You can try Hello moon or Helius products, they have free tiers.

Thanks! Which Helius products are you referring to?

As much as I know, they in deed require account indexing. You could maybe use helius, as they offer a free-tier to get started.

I did try helius and it doesn't allow it. It also doesn't mention whether the paid tiers allow it or not.

getTokenLargestAccounts --> QuickNode
I guess you can also make a call for programaccounts on quicknode also.

Unfortunately they require credit card just to try the free tier, but thanks.

well they dont charge you for free tier.

I did get the getProgramError using alchemy RPC url so I resorted to using the Helius RPC URL and it worked.
https://dashboard.helius.dev/
Note: Both are free plans
